# nasm input/output to window

Tags: nasm, tasm

Ive been from tasm from a while and now migrating to nasm. One thing I notice is that given this code

```
mov ah,00h
int 16h

cmp ah,3Bh
je aaaa
jne bbbb
```

why is that if i compiled and link and run it in nasm, it doesnt produce a window like a command prompt that waits for my keyboard input (it just finishes executes by closing it)? before, this code works well in tasm and when i run it, it opens a prompt and then waits my keyboard entry.

(One thing I notice in tasm is that int 21h function 01,02,09 seems to work well but here in nasm, it doesnt). Thanks

Thanks

Comment: it appears that int 21, int 16 that works in tasm doesnt work well in nasm

Comment: technically in tasm, the program waits the user to enter the F1 key. if it receives scan code of F1, it proceeds to aaaa

Comment: That depends on what kind of executable you're building. If you're building real mode DOS executables in both cases then there should absolutely not be any difference, assuming that you made the necessary code changes to handle syntax differences between tasm and nasm. If you're building protected mode DOS executables then this would depend on the DOS extender(s) you're using. And if you're building a Windows console application with nasm it's certainly not going to work because nearly all interrupts are off-limits for Windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

JMP $ LOOPS THE WINDOW INDEFFENITELY,
THIS IS BAD.
INSTEAD DETECT KEYPRESS FOR ENTER,
ADD A CONDITION LIKE A WHILE LOOP TO DETERMINE IF TO GO TO IT YOU CAN DETECT KEY PRESS TO BREAK THE CONDITION

Comment: Hello, please read [Why is it considered inappropriate and unprofessional to type in all capital letters?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-inappropriate-and-unprofessional-to-type-in-all-capital-letters). Thank you.